# NodeJS and RethinkDB - How to handle connection interruption (connection retry) when listening for table changes (realtime)?

Tags: node.js, express, rethinkdb

```
ReqlRuntimeError: Connection is closed in:
r.table("users").changes()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    at ReqlRuntimeError.ReqlError [as constructor] (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:23:13)
    at new ReqlRuntimeError (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:90:51)
    at mkErr (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/util.js:177:10)
    at Feed.IterableResult._promptNext (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/cursor.js:169:16)
    at Feed.IterableResult._addResponse (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/cursor.js:84:12)
    at TcpConnection.<anonymous> (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:360:22)
    at TcpConnection.cancel (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/util.js:26:16)
    at TcpConnection.cancel (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:789:43)
    at wrappedCb (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:270:17)
    at /home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:280:18
    at tryCatcher (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._resolveFromResolver (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:483:31)
    at new Promise (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:71:37)
    at TcpConnection.<anonymous> (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:264:33)
    at TcpConnection.close (/home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/util.js:43:16)
    at /home/user/DEV/express-socketio/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:782:46
[ERROR] 22:55:08 ReqlRuntimeError: Connection is closed in:
r.table("users").changes()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I had this error when executing a test as following:

1. My nodejs is listening for changes in a table (realtime),
2. then I simulate a connection interruption by turning off the rethinkdb docker container
3. and the error breaks the whole application.

I'm looking for how to handle this kind of error, so the application knows the connection was lost,
but, in some way, after a period of X minutes/seconds/etc, try to reconnect, or even restart the application, I don't know...

I found this https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4886,
but nothing about avoiding app crash or trying to reconnect after a connection loss.

How can I proceed with this? Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/) isn't that complete.  Consider this code that might run when a websocket is opened on a server:

```
// write every change to file

function onChange(err, cursor) {
  // log every change to console
  // Change format: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/
  cursor.each(console.log);

  // if file not open, open file 
  openFile()

  // write changes to file
  cursor.each(writeChangesToFile)

  // if you decide you no longer want these changes
  if (stopChangesNow) {
    cursor.close() // https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#close-cursor
    cancel()
  }
}

// stop writing changes

function cancel(stream) {
  // close file opened above
  closeFile()
}

try {
  r.table('users').changes().run(conn, onChange)
} catch(e) {
  cancel()
}
```

You need the `run()` so your application can process the changes.

You might not need the `cancel()` function unless you need to cleanup a socket, output stream, file handles, etc.  You need the try/catch to keep from crashing.

When a REST server crashes, it only terminates requests in progress.

When a websocket server crashes, it terminates all it's sessions causing problems for a lot more users.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I'll try the 'try/catch' approach as soon as possible and return results

Comment: @GuilhermeAbacherli you're welcome.  Don't forget to mark a correct answer :-)

Comment: Thank you again! This time I tested it with NestJS framework and it worked (I don't think the framework has changed much of the overall functioning of the app, I think it's the same use case).

This solved the "total crash" problem. Now for connection handle/retry, I will look into one of the mentioned libraries in their page:
https://rethinkdb.com/docs/frameworks-and-libraries .

Maybe one of these libs for connection pool: 
https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash ,
https://github.com/hden/rethinkdb-pool .

Comment: Using https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash for connections pool solved my problem with connection break and reconnect, etc. Also it has some more "advanced" features that can be configured.